# How can I obfuscate some Javascript files in the assets of my Android Project?

Tags: javascript, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project where I have some javascript files in assets.
I want them to be obfuscated in production build. As I understand what I need is some console tool for obfuscation and then setup my build.gradle file to use it. Does anybody have any experience implementing something like that?

Comment: you can use [gulp-javascript-obfuscator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-javascript-obfuscator) or [webpack-obfuscator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-obfuscator)

Comment: how do I intergate with gradle though?